# What are some tehniques to understand your client needs

Tags: research

So a client approached me with an original concept that he wants to convert into wireframes. We had an introductory meeting and I left confused.

Now we scheduled a work meeting next week but I realised that it will be kind off hard to grasp my head around the concept.

The concept is something never made into software so there is no competition analysis.

The concept is somewhat a dashboard with games dedicated to businesses and employees and the client is very passionate about this and  throws ideas.

I worked on many projects and usually I get an overview even from a 5 minute discussions but for this one I am afraid that I won't be able to understand it so please let me know what methods you apply you make sure you have your requirements right from the client ?

Answer (score 1):

Do very lo-fi wireframes with incomplete functionality, prioritizing the **most important features** as best you can. Wireframing is part of the communication process, and once you have an incomplete product in front of you to talk about, progress will be easier. When your client talks about features X, Y, and Z, it's difficult to do much other than take it all in. Once you have mocked up something that is *not quite* what your client described (for example, your wireframes include X, Y, but not Z), you can now at least start talking about what trade-offs need to be made in order to move forward. Sometimes, you just have to **make a guess** about what the client wants, they will tell you why your guess is wrong, and that's design.